# Node JS Express app.get() script in different page

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following script in my index.js page -

```js
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    response.render('index', {
        foo: "bar"
    })
})
```

This is working fine, but I want to have the `response.render` code in a different file, as there is going to be a lot of code behind it.
Or basically, I want to get another file to call the `app.get()` method for the `root ("/")` path, and some other file to call the method for the `'/admin'` path, and another for `'/post'` path. Any way to do it ?

Comment: Your question isn't making sense.  You say you want "response.render code in a different page", but there aren't pages in your code.  There are files or modules.   Is that what you meant - you want the render code in a different module?  Also, don't forget that route handlers are just normal Javascript.   If you want to be able to call the same code from several different route handlers, then just put that shared code into its own separate function and then call that function from each place that you want to use it from.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant, like having an 'admin.js' file that has the app.get('/admin') code, and it should be imported into the index.js file. Is it possible ?

Comment: Yes, that's just normal module development in nodejs.  You can put whatever functions you want in some other module file and then import that other module so you can call those functions.  This has nothing at all to do with routes.  This is just regular module development in nodejs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could do is create a new javascript file with export modules to handle the routes.  I'm not sure if you will be able to move the `app.get()` methods to a different JS file, but here's something you can do:

**server.js**:

```js
const manageIndexRoute = require("./manageindex.js");
app.get('/', manageIndexRoute)
```

**manageindex.js**

```js
module.exports = (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', {
    foo: "bar",
    ...
  })
  ...
}
```